# Android: Want to show layout on top when user scroll up and hide when scroll down in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-gesture, android-websettings

I'm building an application in which I have loaded the webpage on webview. I have one layout which contains edittext in that. I want to hide the layout when user is scrolling down in the webview and show it again when user scrolls to the top. I have tried using `onTouch` but it only takes the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and all that. Here what my code looks like:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.web
            && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(CLICK_ON_URL, 2000);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == CLICK_ON_URL) {
        top.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see here I'm using `top.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);`, but this is not solving my problem, it completely hides my layout.

Any idea how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may wrap both your layout and the webView inside a scrollView. So that when the user scrolls down, the parent will catch the scroll event. For reference,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_main" >

<!-- Both your views goes here -->

</ScrollView>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my project is at its end phase and right now changing the layouts and all will be a tough job for me. Can't we do it programmatically without the touching the layouts?

Comment: this change wont affect your program in any way
just add both the layout with editText and webview inside scrollview
you dont need to write code for that in your class

Comment: @Hari - What should I write in the code for capturing that? Till that time I'm integrating both the layouts in scroll view. Thanks.

Comment: you dont need to write code for scrollView just edit the xml and run the program

Comment: @Hari: Have you seen the latest FourSquare app. In that what they have done is that they have captured the gesture of the scroll and accordingly animating the layout to appear and disappear from the bottom. I want to use the same effect in my application. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I have not seen that app but I think you want animation effects